# Android Tablet Won't Stay Off

Tags: battery, charging, hardware, rom, power-on

I have a Cube U30GT Mini tablet with Android 4.1.1, kernel 3.0.8, Rockchip rk3066. This tablet won't stay off unless the battery is dead.

Doing a normal "Power Off" just reboots the tablet.

If the battery is dead and I plug in the charger it always boots.

I also tried removing the memory card, but that didn't help either.

Is there any setting or Linux kernel tweak which could be causing this issue, or any other ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: Is the device rooted. First thought is defective hardware

Comment: Although this sounds like defective hardware, possibly a power switch or moisture issue... Have you tried `adb shell reboot --poweroff` ?

Comment: Device is rooted. I tried `reboot --poweroff` and same problem. The switch is working, it almost seems like it's some sort of inherent feature of this tablet or some low-level boot loader problem. I just figured out that if I hold in the power button (hard reset) while it is booting, then it will shut off and remain off. But in order to turn it on again after that I have to connect the charger. I first thought I'd bricked it when it happened, but luckily connecting the charger woke it. Still a complete mystery why it doesn't normally stay off.

Comment: Why not try flashing original firmware? It will help rule out hardware issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Options were enabled in Settings. Disabling them fixed the issue.